# The same outgoing and incoming degree in graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

I have an undirected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. How to determinate in $poly (n, m)$, is it possible (and how is it necessary) to orient all the edges so that each vertex has the same outgoing and
incoming degree.

Answer (score 7):

If such an orientation is possible, then all degrees are even. Conversely, if all degrees are even then the graph is Eulerian. Orient the edges according to an Eulerian circuit.